# What is the benefit of using a "document-oriented DBMS"?

Tags: nosql, document-oriented-db

I must be missing something, because everything I've seen so far suggests that it isn't any more interesting than a single table for storing blobs and a second table for tags that apply to it.

Now I certainly can see some benefit to that from a design pattern, but why would I want to use a "document-oriented DBMS" instead of just building it using a traditional database like SQL Server, Oracle, or Postgres?

Answer (score 4):

I enjoyed listening to the [floss weekly episode](http://twit.tv/floss36) about CouchDB. Lots of reasoning and ideas there.

Prior to listening, most of the stuff I read about this topic triggered not much insight (for me). Listening to people talking and reasoning about why&where you want to use document-oriented DBs helped me a lot to really get the concepts, reasoning, pros and cons. Now all the articles and statements (IMHO) suddenly make a lot more sense.

Your mileage may vary, but this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are meaning products such as Couch DB or Tokyo Cabinet (rather than ECM products like Documentum).  I think the attraction for many developers is familiarity.

Firstly, the conceptual model (in most cases) is key-value pairs, like a configuration file.  As most frameworks seem to require a lot of configuration-wrangling, front-end/middle tier developers are comfortable with that way of working working.  Secondly, these tools offer interfaces in developer-friendly languages like Java, Python, etc.

Whereas, traditional RDBMS products require thinking in a different fashion - relationally.  And they require learning not just a weird language, SQL, but a new way of programming: set-based rather than procedural.  If you rehearse the arguments for putting business logic in the middle tier rather stored procedures in the database, well a lot of them apply to No SQL as well.

Comment: Documentum is one of the most vile pieces of overpriced enterprise software ever perpetrated.

Comment: If you are looking for a key-value model, relational databases have no problem doing that. That's just a two-column table. Heck, one of the columns is even referred to as a "primary key".

Comment: @JonathanAllen - using a relational data product (e.g. Oracle, MySQL) to hold key-value pairs is rather missing the point.

Comment: It's just another design pattern that developers need to know in order to fully take advantage of their database. Over the last five years, every database I've built has had at least one Key+XML or Key+JSON table. Setting up an entire other server for that one table would be madness.

Answer (score 0):

> why would I want to use a "document-oriented DBMS" instead of just
>   building it using a traditional database like SQL Server, Oracle, or
>   Postgres?

Historically document-oriented DBMS do not allow to span ACID transactions across documents. They have poor support for *Foreign Keys*. The trade ought to allow for more accessible operations, maintenance and scaling.